# QStringListModel sorting

Tags: c++, qt

How can sort QStringListModel?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

By using the [`sort`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstringlistmodel.html#sort) method.

Comment: The `QStringListModel::sort()` method is not reimplemented from the `QAbstractItemModel::sort()` in Qt version prior to 4.6. You will need Qt 4.6 for the sort method to behave correctly.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the `QStringListModel::sort()` method is to use the `QStringList::sort()` method on the string list stored into the model. This approach is not as efficient as using the `QStringListModel::sort()`.

```
QStringList list = stringListModel->stringList();
list.sort();
stringListModel->setStringList(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)

```
QListView* view = new QListView;
QStringListModel* model = new QStringListModel(this);
QSortFilterProxyModel* proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);

proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
view->setModel(proxyModel);
```

Then all you have to do is sort your proxy model with the sort method:

```
void QSortFilterProxyModel::sort(
  int column, Qt::SortOrder order = Qt::AscendingOrder):
```

Since a string list model has only one column:

```
proxyModel->sort(0);
```

Additionally, if you want to sort your model each time a new row is inserted, you can use a connect to sort the proxyModel:

```
connect(model, &QStringListModel::rowsInserted,
  this, [proxyModel](){ proxyModel->sort(0); });
```